# Using std::shared_ptr for managing std::mutex lifetime and lock/unlock - is this a good practice?

Tags: c++, locking, mutex, shared-ptr

I've written a Lock class that employs a `std::shared_ptr` to handle a `std::mutex` object's lifecycle, including lock/unlock operations. I'm aware that `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` are more commonly used for the latter. Additionally, the std::mutex here isn't dynamically allocated, which isn't the usual case for `std::shared_ptr` usage. Are those valid concerns? and are these practices acceptable or potentially problematic?
Thank you.

```
#include <mutex>
std::mutex mtx;
struct Lock
{
    Lock(std::mutex* pmtx) :
        psmtx(pmtx, [this](std::mutex* pmtx_) {(*this)(pmtx_); })

    {

        std::cout << "Lock()\n";
        psmtx->lock();

    }

    void operator()(std::mutex* pmtx)
    {
        std::cout << "~Lock()\n";
        pmtx->unlock();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> psmtx;
};

int main()
{

    Lock   lockA(&mtx);
    Lock   lockB(lockA);
    Lock   lockC(lockB);

}
```

Comment: Although your `mutex` is not dynamically allocated, the control block of the `shared_ptr` will be. Your class only accepts `std::mutex`, yet you've written the example code as if it's `std::recursive_mutex`. The standard lock guards use templates to support different mutex types. Since your class cannot be used with `nullptr`, do not make the constructor accept a pointer. The use of operator overloading for unlocking is totally unnecessary, and making that method public is dangerous. Similarly, you do not need a lambda to invoke it, as a simple (private) static function would suffice.

Comment: Further, by allowing this lock to be copied, you can find yourself in the awkward scenario where one thread thinks the mutex is locked but another thread unlocked it explicitly which is super dangerous. This is a variation on the same theme mentioned before, as not only is your "unlock" method public, but so is the mutex itself. Further to the lambda issue, the fact that it captures `this`, but that object can go out of scope even if copies of the lock remain, then if you ever try to use some member of `Lock` via that pointer you're in for a bad time.

Comment: To actually answer the (somewhat subject to opinion) question, it's okay in general to use `std::shared_ptr` to manage resources that are not dynamically allocated, while gaining the benefits that `std::shared_ptr` provides (atomicity/thread-safety, reference counting, and weak pointers). It is quite powerful and flexible in that regard. The main concerns I have here are largely centered around _how_ you are applying it. Probably this is a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: *"to handle a `std::mutex` object's lifecycle, including lock/unlock operations"* -- looks more like "only" than "including". The most significant parts of an object's lifecycle are construction and destruction, and your class makes no attempt to manage either of these events. (Unless... do you think it tries to handle destruction because it uses a smart pointer?) Could you add a description of what the intended functionality is? Not just a vague "handle lifecycle", but getting into details like "when X happens, the lock is released".

Comment: The shown code does not compile. My C++ compiler doesn't know anything about that mysterious `LockShared` class, so the shown code cannot be meaningfully analyzed. In any case, what can be determined about the shown code is that it creates many opportunities for undefined behavior.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry. I had created two classes and somehow it got mixed up when copying and pasting here. i fixed all the issues.

Comment: @JaMiT fixed that one.

Comment: Your class could be replaced with `std::make_shared<std::unique_lock>(mtx)` if you really need to do this

Comment: Now that the (hopefully) real code has been posted, one of its defects seems to be rather obvious: it looks like the mutex gets unlocked the first time any `Lock` goes out of scope, after it's copy-constructed, and the destructor of the first `Lock` that gets destroyed unlocks the mutex. Other `Lock`s remain in existence but the mutex is now unlocked. Fail.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i don't think so? The shared pointer being destroyed unlocks the mutex, as that's copied in the copy constructors it's the last `Lock` being destroyed that unlocks the mutex

Comment: Oh, it's even worse, actually, now that you pointed out that little detail. The destructor captures `this` of the first `Lock` object. If it gets copy-constructed, and the original object gets destroyed before the copy-constructed object, the deleter gets invoked with a `this` of a destroyed object, and this definitely results in undefined behavior.